# How do I hide or lock Android's Internal Memory when connected to PC?

Tags: internal-storage, usb, usb-debugging, android-pc

When connecting any Android Device to PC it will show both internal memory and external memory (SD Card), is it possible to hide or lock the internal memory to avoid deleting or messing with apps files?

The device we're using is a Chinese Android Tablet:

Name & Model: Eken E902
Build Number: astar_m900-eng 4.4.2 KVT49L 20160322 test-keys
Kernel Version: 3.4.39
Firmware is exdroid4.4.2_r2-a33-v2.1
O/S version is Kitkat 4.4..2

Comment: Can't you just change it so that the default on connection is USB Charge instead of MTP? The exact process would vary based on make, model, and android versions, which you did not state... please update your original question with the necessary information.

Comment: I still wanna keep SD Card connective so students can print their researches  or pics while the internal memory has the apps' files and info which I don't anyone to mess with. I've update the question with the device info.

Comment: Hmm... I understand now, but I don't think this is possible even if you are rooted.

Comment: Sounds no luck to do that so better to disable USB completely and keep it for charging only right? Another quick question and thanks for your support. I've installed a Kiosk Mode App and locked almost all critical system apps I just wanna allow Screen Lock so each Student can protect his tablet. I managed to install a WiFi Manager but now remains the Screen Lock and I can't find any suitable on playstore.